# Deleting all keychain passwords on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, password, keychain

I want to delete all keychain passwords. I want to use my computer without any keychains.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use Keychain...

Answer (score 1):

Keychain Access is built into macOS that stores your passwords, certificates and other sensitive information securely.

You cannot completely delete or disable Keychain Access, but you can delete individual keychains and keys.

1. Keychain Access
2. Select the passwords you want to delete
3. Right mouse click and choose delete

For further use:

- You must deselect save password in Keychain (when you get a popup, to enter your password)
- Also don't save passwords in Safari (they are also stored in Keychain)
- Third party apps will store you passwords in Keychain. Because it is the safest place on the Mac to store sensitive data like passwords and keys.